# React Native setBackgroundMessageHandler not triggering on quit state on physical device

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have a RN app that uses firebase for push notification. as per docs, declare setBackgroundMessageHandler before registerComponent like this:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log("BG MESSAGE", remoteMessage);
})
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

I can see the console log in the metro on background state but on quit state, there is no console message.

**Plot twist**, On emulator, the notification is receive on background and quit state.

**More Plot twist**, On emulator, with or without setBackgroudMessageHandler, the notification will still be received on background and quit state. On Physical device, only on background state. Though it will always return a warning that states need setBackgroudMessageHandler.

No issues with iOS.

We use react-native-push-notification for local notifications.

```
"react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "11.5.0",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
```

Comment: Did you found any solution?